# Is it valid to multiply both sides of an equation by a complex number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

In case I'd like to get rid of some complex denominators, could I multiply both sides of the equation by the common denominator?
I understand there's an other way, but i'd like to know if the above mentioned would be a valid operation, and if not, why.

Comment: Look up the definition of a FIELD.... $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R, \mathbb C$ are fields. In a field if $z\ne 0$ then $x=y\iff zx=zy.$... And in a field, if $d_1,...,d_n$ are all non-zero then their product $z$ is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWainfleet, this helps me a lot. I had empiric results, but I wasn't sure how to prove it.

Comment: You can multiply both sides by an elephant as far as anyone cares.  If $a = b$ then "doing anything you like to $a$" = "doing the exact same thing to $b$" because $a$ and $b$ are the exact same thing.  And if you do something to $a$ you *ARE* do it to $b$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\left(\mbox{some expression}\right)=\left(\mbox{another expression}\right)$, this means that both expressions evaluate to *the same complex number*. Let's call this number $z$. This means that:
$$z=\left(\mbox{some expression}\right)=\left(\mbox{another expression}\right)$$
Well, if you want to multiply both sides by another complex, say $w$, the equality will still hold, because both $w\cdot\left(\mbox{some expression}\right)$ and $w\cdot\left(\mbox{another expression}\right)$ are just the same as $w\cdot z$.

Beware that if $w$ is $0$ (that is, if you want to multiply both sides by zero), then the equality will still hold: it will be just $0=0$. Of course, this is not useful---you *lost all the information* you had in your original equation, because you can't divide both sizes by $0$ to get back where you started.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid as long as the multiplier you use isn't zero.

It's even valid to multiply both sides by a *variable* expression, but again you must include the proviso that variable multiplier cannot be zero. Many are under the mistaken impression that this is not valid, but it is -- you just have to include the additional assumption to the end.

For example, suppose you have the equation $x=1$. It is perfectly valid to multiply both sides by $x$, with the proviso that $x\neq 0$:
$$x=1$$
$$x(x)=x(1)\tag{$x\neq 0$}$$
$$x^2=x\tag{$x\neq 0$}$$
$$x^2-x = 0\tag{$x\neq 0$}$$
$$x(x-1)=0\tag{$x\neq 0$}$$
This equation *appears* to have an additional solution -- but don't forget that $x=0$ is *not* a solution since it is excluded by the proviso.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid. You can still multiply both sides of an equation by a scalar and still have it hold. It's just like the real numbers.